# invoke template with `const&`?

Tags: c++, templates

This appears to be legal

```
template<const int& x, int y>void fn() {}
```

However how do I call it? If it is the y type only `fn<1>()` seems to work (but not `fn<intvar>()`). The const& is confusing me especially when intvar doesn't seem to work with int y. Is this completely wrong/illegal? I'm using clang 3.2

Comment: I'd say you're allowed to pass a reference to a `const int` member/variable (that can be deduced at compile time), but not to a variable value. How's `intvar` declared for the case you've been testing?

Comment: @g-makulik: `int i=9; fn<i>()` heres what clang says http://pastebin.com/37VfCRiu

Comment: Did you try `const int i=9; fn<i>()`? I think the possibility that a simple global variable can be changed anywhere, and template  function instances can be declared anywhere it shouldn't work IMHO.

Comment: that works if its declared global but not in main()/myfunction.

Comment: That's strange of course, I see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a reference to an `int` with static storage duration and external linkage:

```
template<const int& x, int y>void fn() {}

int x = 0;

int main() {
    fn<x,2>();
}
```

I think C++11 has relaxed the requirement for external linkage, but the compiler I tried still complained if it didn't have that.

Comment: Clang 3.4. accepts an object with internal linkage, gcc 4.8 doesn't still.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Why not? A `const` reference can bind to a non-`const` object; and it's the address, not the value, that's needed to instantiate the template, so no requirement for the value to be a compile-time constant. Demonstration: http://ideone.com/5JCxCJ

Comment: My head hurts. http://ideone.com/5tBnLH i'm debugging i knew i wasn't crazy when I said it didn't work w/o const

Comment: @acidzombie24: That attempts to use a non-const *value* as the other template parameter `y`; of course that won't work. Using a reference to a non-const variable as the *reference* parameter `x`, as my example does, is fine.

Comment: Correct I just figured that out as well.

Answer (score 2):

External linkage is required for references & pointers for template parameters
(for C++11, internal linkage, but static storage duration is required)

So if you have to use `const int &` as a template argument, you need to have it as `extern` in global scope.

```
extern const int a = 2;
fn<a,1>();
```

Comment: The linkage can be internal. What's required is static storage duration.

Comment: `extern` declaration and initialisation, I don't understand. Can you elaborate this?

Comment: @g-makulik: `extern` means it has external linkage; initialisation means this is the definition.

Comment: @jrok gcc 4.6.1 rejects if `extern` is not used

Comment: It works i'll just add it must be global and not inside of the calling function

Comment: @acidzombie24 yeah I already mentioned that, if you want you can make it **bold**

Comment: oops, i was rushing out and didnt remember if i saw that in your answer, comment or other answer/comment. -edit- still a stupid comment because you clearly have extern there and that only makes sense at global/namespace scope